# How to use a custom UIButton category with Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I'm coding a simple card game for my younger sister on a whim. I'm using UIButtons: default state is face down, selected state is face up. I need the buttons to have a boolean property that tells me if they've ever been flipped over. If not, it gets set to true (that way I'm not just drawing random cards on each flip). I tried creating a category of UIButton called CardGameButton. In the .h file:

```
@interface UIButton (CardGameButton)
@property (nonatomic) BOOL discovered;
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation UIButton (CardGameButton)
@dynamic discovered;
@end
```

This is really all I need. How do I use this in IB? I have a bunch of UIButtons on a screen that I want to be CardGameButtons. But when I try to switch my calls to UIButton in my view controller to CardGameButton, it tells me CardGameButton isn't a type (yes I imported the file). And when I try to switch the class of the UIButtons in the storyboard to CardGameButtons, the console tells me that they're an "unknown class". I tried subclassing UIButton, but that didn't work (I just need them to be RoundedRectButtons with the extra property, and since you can't subclass RoundedRectButton they wouldn't display properly). How do I make this work in IB?

Comment: Since categories can't have properties, I would suggest you just use a custom button, and do whatever drawing you want, or use a UIImageView with a tap gesture recognizer attached to it as your "button".

Answer (score 1):

You're treating `CardGameButtons` as though it's a subclass of UIButton when instead it's a category. Anything you declare as `UIButton` will have the `discovered` property as standard, but you can't 'create' a `CardGameButtons` as it's not a thing in itself.

Comment: But categories can't add any storage, so you can't add any properties (at least ones that have a backing ivar).

Answer (score 0):

Categories are not types. They're just used to add some extended behavior to the class.

I suggest that you try subclassing `UIButton` and call it `CardGameButton`. Add the `BOOL` property to its interface. You can still make it a round rect button, by setting `buttonType` to `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` **"round rect buttons aren't a separate subclass."**. Then override

```
- (void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(event.type == UIEventTypeTouches){
        self.discovered = YES; // or handle the logic as you want here
    }
    [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];
}
```

You can add a `UIButton` to your view from the IB, and then its class to your created subclass and set its type to round rect.

---

**Edit**: As you stated, `buttonType` is actually `readOnly`, so we can't use that to draw a round rect button. However, it turns out that it's not hard to draw it.

Check [this tutorial](http://pocketcyclone.com/2011/08/30/a-simple-way-to-create-custom-rounded-rect-buttons/). It shows how to do it using `CALayer` property of `UIButton` and using `UIBezeirPath`.

Comment: buttonType is a readonly property though. Am I doing something wrong here?
`-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
 if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
  self.buttonType = UIButtonTypeRoundedRect;
 }
}`

Comment: Actually, you're right. `buttonType` is read only. It seems that you'll have to draw it yourself. Check my edit.